# Fixing the flipped/inverted Y axis in the xarray with rasterio

Tags: rasterio, xarray

The data I read with xarray with rasterio engine is inverted along Y axis (This is SMAPL4 data). The correct dimension values are y=ds.y*(-1).

```
ds = xr.open_mfdataset(file_paths, engine="rasterio", chunks=chunks, combine='nested', concat_dim='time', parallel=True)
```

[image]

How can I fix this, without messing up the chunks?

**Debug attempt 1**

```
ds = ds.reindex(y=ds.y*(-1))
```

Result: The chunking over the y-axis disappears. Plus, numeric values in the variable data field somehow disappears.

**Debug attempt 2:**

```
ds= ds.isel(y=slice(None, None, -1))
```

Result: This code just re-selects the grids and does not change the dimension values themselves

**Debug attempt 3:**

```
ds= ds.reindex_like(ds_template)
```

Result: Again, numeric values within precipitation data disappear

**Debug attempt 4:**
Change engine from rasterio to default (auto-detect).

```
ds = xr.open_mfdataset(file_paths, chunks=chunks, combine='nested', concat_dim='time', parallel=True)
```

Result: My file has some issues with the default engine; the data is read as "attributes."

Comment: In discussion with @raraki we've found a solution at least partly using xarray netcdf4-engine. Using rasterio-engine works too, but only for the original Earth Data dataset. Please follow up in https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/7621. It would be great if raraki could wrap this up and present as answer here.

Comment: Hi @kmuehlbauer, thanks a lot for your help. I will post it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a better way to set the coordinates. For the SMAP dataset, you have to assign "cell_lat" and "cell_lon" as the coordinates of the dataset, and use them to plot. I am posting on behalf of [kmuehlbauer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/221294/kmuehlbauer) based on our discussion in [the Github issue](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/7621). Thank you kmuehlbauer!

```
Import xarray as xr
```

### Use xarray with netcdf engine

```
# load root group with coordinates
ds_NSIDC_root = xr.open_dataset(os.path.join(input_path, fn), group="/", engine='netcdf4')

# load data from Geophysical_Data group
ds_NSIDC_precip = xr.open_dataset(os.path.join(input_path, fn), group="Geophysical_Data", engine='netcdf4')

# merge groups
ds_NSIDC = xr.merge([ds_NSIDC_root, ds_NSIDC_precip])

# plot
ds_NSIDC.precipitation_total_surface_flux.plot()
# the above is essentially the same as 
# ds_NSIDC.precipitation_total_surface_flux.plot(x="x", y="y")
```

[image]

### Use xarray with rasterio engine

```
ds_NASA_download_rasterio = xr.open_dataset(os.path.join(input_path, fn), engine='rasterio')
ds_NASA_download_rasterio = ds_NASA_download_rasterio.set_coords(["cell_lat", "cell_lon"])
ds_NASA_download_rasterio.Geophysical_Data_precipitation_total_surface_flux[0].plot(y="cell_lat", x="cell_lon")
```

[image]

Note that the rasterio method only works for files directly downloaded from NASA Earth Data, and not preprocessed data on the NSIDC server.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the sign of the coordinates like this:

```
# Create an example dataset
ds = xr.Dataset({"data": ("x", np.arange(11))}, 
                coords = {"x": np.arange(-5,6,1)})

print(f"[x =-4]: {ds['data'].sel(x=-4).values}")

# Make the negative coordinates positive and vice versa.
ds = ds.assign_coords({"x": ds.x * -1})

print(f"[x =-4]: {ds['data'].sel(x=-4).values}")
```

Gives:

```
>>> [x = -4]: 1
>>> [x = -4]: 9
```

Comment: I am coming to think this is a bug in the dataset, and cannot be fixed. Even if you sort the data according to Y coordinate, the original coordinates dont change.

Comment: Yeah you're right, think my updated answer will fix your problem.

Comment: Agreed, that's the only way left and I incorporated it to my code. Thank you, Bert!